# PHP manual OOP visibility example - can someone explain it

Tags: php, oop

I saw this in the PHP OOP manual http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.visibility.php and I can't get my head around why the output is not: Foo::testPrivate Foo::testPublic

```
class Bar 
{
    public function test() {
        $this->testPrivate();
        $this->testPublic();
    }

    public function testPublic() {
        echo "Bar::testPublic\n";
    }

    private function testPrivate() {
        echo "Bar::testPrivate\n";
    }
}

class Foo extends Bar 
{
    public function testPublic() {
        echo "Foo::testPublic\n";
    }

    private function testPrivate() {
        echo "Foo::testPrivate\n";
    }
}

$myFoo = new foo();
$myFoo->test(); // Bar::testPrivate 
                // Foo::testPublic
```

Comment: Hint:  you'll get the desired output if you change `private` to `protected`.  Read about both access modifiers.

Comment: check this thread out. The first answer helps me a lot. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12794290/php-manual-visibilty-example-confused

Comment: Check this thread out. The first answer helps me a lot. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12794290/php-manual-visibilty-example-confused

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It's all about the visibility of the variables / methods.

You'll notice that in the `Bar` class, the method `testPrivate()` is `private`.  That means that ONLY itself can access that method.  No children.

So when `Foo` extends `Bar`, and then asks to run the `test()` method, it does two things:

1. It overrides the `testPublic()` method because it's public, and `Foo` has the right to override it with it's own version.
2. It calls `test()` **on `Bar`** (since `test()` only exists on `Bar()`).

`testPrivate()` is **not** overridden, and is part of the class that holds `test()`.  Therefore, `Bar::testPrivate` is printed.
`testPublic()` **is** overridden, and is part of the inheriting class.  Therefore, `Foo::testPublic` is printed.

Comment: Right. Thanks @rockerest for a clean explanation.

Comment: But if you `echo $this->testPrivate()` from within `Foo:testPublic`, it will echo `Foo::testPrivate`. So it looks like it was overridden when called from this context. Now I'm confused!

Comment: @bfavaretto Remember, `$this` is a dynamic variable that references the class that the code is in.  So while it's processing `test()`, `$this` references the temporary copy of the `Bar` class (giving you `Bar::testPrivate()`), but `$this` inside the `Foo` class will reference the `Foo` class (giving you `Foo::testPrivate()`).

Comment: @rockerest I did some further research, and still find it confusing. I undertand it works as you say, but could you recommend an article or docs where I can further understand how inheritance works internally in PHP? Using reflection, for example, I can't find any trace of the temporary copy of `Bar` you mentioned -- `get_class($this)` always output `Foo`.

Comment: @bfavaretto Where is your `get_class()` call?  Inside `Bar`?  Or in `Foo`?  It might be best to ask your own question, with the exact code you have and what you are expecting to happen, and what actually happens.  On the other hand, there might already be a question about this somewhere on SO.

Comment: @rockerest Agreed, created a new [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9436352/behavior-of-this-on-inherited-methods). Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

In some cases, it is easy to notice that you want a **private** method on the **Bar** class, but you also wants the **Foo** class to access it. 
But wait, it is public or private? 
Here comes the **protected** modifier. 
When a method is **private**, only the class itself can call the method.
When a method is **public**, everyone can call it, like a free party.
When a method is **protected**, the class itself can call it and also whoever inhered this method (children) will be able to call it as a method of their own.

Answer (score -1):

I posted the same question few days ago... because this behaviour wasnt logical for me either.
$this is always referred to the current object which it is used in. In my opinion example like this should throw an error or warning or something. Because in the above example you are actually accessing private members :SSS WHICH SUPPOSED TO BE INACCESSIBLE!

Comment: Not a constructive answer. You can leave a comment with something constructive and not a rant.