# php manual visibility example confused

Tags: php, visibility

I have confused from an example in php manual. It's about visibility. Here is the example.

```
class Bar {
    public function test() {
        $this->testPrivate();
        $this->testPublic();
    }
    public function testPublic() {
        echo "Bar::testPublic\n";
    }
    private function testPrivate() {
        echo "Bar::testPrivate\n";
    }
}
class Foo extends Bar {
    public function testPublic() {
        echo "Foo::testPublic\n";
    }
    private function testPrivate() {
        echo "Foo::testPrivate\n";
    }
}
$myFoo = new foo();
$myFoo->test();  
?>
```

http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.visibility.php

This example outputs

```
Bar::testPrivate 
Foo::testPublic
```

Please can you explain how this happen?

**why both `testPublic()` are not called?**

I put a **`var_dump($this)`** in Bar class construct. It prints `object(Foo)[1]`. The thing I know is private properties can be called withing same class.

**Then how "`Bar::testPrivate`" is called?**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Then how "Bar::testPrivate" is called?

When you call `$myFoo->test()`, it runs the code in the context of `Bar` because the `Foo` class didn't override it.

Inside `Bar::test()`, when `$this->testPrivate()` gets called, the interpreter will look at `Foo` first but that method is private (and private methods from descendent classes can't be called from `Bar`), so it goes one level up until it can find a suitable method; in this case that would be `Bar::testPrivate()`.

In contrast, when `$this->testPublic()` gets called, the interpreter immediately finds a suitable method in `Foo` and runs it.

**Edit**

> why both testPublic() are not called?

Only one method gets called when you run `$this->testPublic()`, the furthest one (in terms of distance to the base class).

If `Foo::testPublic()` needs to also execute the parent's implementation, you should write `parent::testPublic()` inside that method.

Comment: +1 And why can't `test()` (which is `Bar`'s `test()`) call `Foo`'s `testPrivate()`? Because it's private, and you don't want parents touching their child's privates, do you?

Comment: Part of the confusion regarding `testPublic()`, I imagine, is that PHP does replacement overriding instead of refinement overriding. This means PHP won't call a parent's method in the child unless you explicitly ask it to do so (eg: `parent::testPublic();`).

Comment: @Jack Thanks bro. You explained it very well. Now I can understand the point. Because $this refers to foo, I thought Foo class private function should be called. It was the point I confused.

Answer (score 2):

Your function lies in the `Bar`class and you are using the magic `$this` pointer to call the member functions.

Try moving the function `test()` to `Foo` class, and see what happens. The output shall be:

```
Foo::testPrivate
Foo::testPublic
```

In your example, the private function of Bar was called because it was applicable only to that class. The class Foo does not have a `test` function in it, and hence the test function from `Bar` class has no access to call them.

Then, class `Foo`'s public function was called instead of `Bar`'s because of function overloading.

Both the classes have a function of that name, so the child class's function has importance.

Answer (score 1):

`Private` doesn't mean you can't call it. It means that you can only call it from the **current class**. `Public` means that you can call it from **any class**.

To call `Bar::testPrivate`, try this:

```
$Bar->testPublic();
```

**or**

```
parent::testPublic();
```

BUT, you can't call `$Bar->testPrivate()` because the method is `private`.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question.

Comment: Sorry, misunderstood the question. Fixed.

Answer (score 1):

You call

```
$myFoo->test();
```

See function `test`:

```
public function test() {
    $this->testPrivate();
    $this->testPublic();
}
```

When this is called on an instance of a `Bar` class (including inherited classes) it invokes `testPrivate` and `testPublic`.

These methods are overridden in class `Foo`, that means the methods of `Foo` are used. You can always call method of a base class:

```
// in Foo
public function testPublic() {
    parent::testPublic();
    echo "Foo::testPublic\n";
}
```

`Bar::testPrivate` is called because it is `private` and not overridden by `Foo::testPrivate`.

See more [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2994758/function-overloading-and-overriding-in-php) or [here](http://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/webprog/pcook/ch07_08.htm).

Answer (score 1):

I guess the comment of user 'omega at 2093 dot es' (http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.visibility.php#109324) is describing the same thing. 
There is said: "Methods defined in a parent class can NOT access private methods defined in a class which inherits from them. They can access protected, though."

In your case `$this` object in `Bar::test()` method is of `Foo` type (your var_dump proves that). Because `Foo::testPrivate()` method is private, it cannot be accessed from parent class Bar, and the only method, which can be accessed remains `Bar::testPrivate()` (try to comment definition, and you'll get fatal error). That is why first output is `Bar::testPrivate`.

The line `$this->testPublic();` calls `Foo::testPublic()` method, because `$this` is of `Foo` type and method is defined as public.

To be short, private methods are accessible only from the class, where they are defined. They cannot be accessed neither from child nor from parent classes.

To make the method accessible from child or parent classes make it protected. For example, if you'll make `testPrivate()` method protected in both classes, it will print `Foo::testPrivate Foo::testPublic`.

Answer (score 0):

The class Foo extends the class Bar. Then the function test is called wich is defined in Bar. In this function are two calls. One to the public and one to the private function in the class Bar.